# Camera not accessible because of feature policy in chrome 64 and 65 beta

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, camera, cross-domain

Chrome 64 has included feature policy for cross-origin-iframe. I need to access the camera inside the cross-origin-iframe.

I had tried loading page which uses camera through form submission it didn't work. But, if I try loading page through source attribute inside the iframe tag directly is working.

```
<!-- This is not working -->
<iframe allow="camera;" id="co-iframe" name="co-iframe"></iframe>
<form action="https://<<cameraAccesingPage>>/" method="get" target="co-iframe">
<button type="submit" name="button">Submit</button>
</form>


<!-- This is working -->
<iframe allow="camera;" src="https://<<cameraAccesingPage>>/" id="co-iframe" name="co-iframe"></iframe>
```

Please refer the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1t7Lfc2a/19/) for more understanding.

Answer (score 2):

One thing to note is that a feature specified within the `allow` attribute is by default only allowed for the origin in the iframe's `src` attribute. So in your first case where you have a form targetting the iframe **where there is no src attribute you would need to add either the all (`*`) flag or rather more restrictively the source origin**.

E.g:

```
<!-- 
Because there is no 'src' specified in the iframe, we need to explicitly 
allow the source for the feature like so: 
allow="camera https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/gum/;"

We could also allow all origins (which is less restrictive!) using allow="camera *;".
-->

<iframe allow="camera https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/gum/;" id="co-iframe" name="co-iframe"></iframe>
<form action="https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/gum/" method="get" target="co-iframe">
    <button type="submit" name="button">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Does this solve your issue?

Comment: Nope 'camera *'  or 'camera *;' do not work in Chrome Version 77.0.3865.90 (Official Build) (64-bit). On firefox the 'camera' just do the job.

Comment: For some reason 'camera;microphone' worked in chrome. I think that having pressed ok in firefox triggered some inconsistency in the previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Why the semicolon? For multiple features use spaces...

```
<iframe allow="geolocation microphone camera midi encrypted-media vr" src="http://somesite.com/"></iframe>
```

Comment: Can you link to a spec for that? The best I can find is this example, which does include semicolons (and also says this is deprecated in 64+): https://dev.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-permissions-in-cross-origin-iframes